# Access denied when opening WMV file from Java application

Tags: java, file, awt, file-extension

I wrote this code in my Java application:

```
URL url = new URL("file://c:\\tmp\\test.wmv");
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url.toURI());
```

If I execute it, Java throws an "access denied" IOException.
Permissions are OK on that file. I renamed that file to "test.txt" so it just has another extension. The result: Notepad opens and shows me the bytes of the file. So it is a problem in executing the media player.
I configured the extension settings, so the media player opens when I click on the file in Windows Explorer. But it's not possible for Java to use this Defaultprogram for the wmv-extension.
What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL("file://c:\\tmp\\test.wmv");
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url.toURI());
```

Should be more along the lines of:

```
File file = new File("c:\\tmp\\test.wmv");
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```